# Efficient 2d drawing strategy for this custom progress bar. Canvas vs OpenGL vs

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics, opengl-es

I need to draw what amounts to basically a customized progress bar that is masked off. Imagine you have something like this

oOoOoOoOOoOoOOOo

where all of those Os represent what is essentially a mask for a progress bar. So at 50 percent progress, the first half of Os are blue filled, the second half are white filled. Imagine each of those Os is about 3dp wide (so we are looking at hundreds of shapes overall.

It is rather important that this progress bar can be drawn efficiently and quickly as progress will change rapidly and will be competing with many other drawing operations at the same time on the page. The progress will be responding to touch events, so it will pretty much be spammed with updates.

Currently: 
I draw my Os into a bitmap to create my mask. In each draw operations, I draw rectangles to represent my progress on the canvas. I then draw my mask on top with the appropriate PorterDuff mode (DST_IN). This works OK, but there is significant slow down when the progress is being dragged.

Main questions are:
Is this a sound strategy?
Would I get a performance benefit from going with OpenGL or something else?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: in oOoOoOoOOoOoOOOo i dont see any 0s (zeros)  so can you explain what you want? image maybe?

Comment: Sorry, they are all O (not zeros), basically circles of different sizes. I am not home at the moment but I can come up with a better example later if that doesn't make sense